# Reactjs firebase authentication action link for Email address verification and Password reset

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have Reacts app and using firebase authentication. So I have sent the Email address verification and Password reset email. So user got the both emails.

For email address verification, when they click action link, they see the "Your email has been verified" default page.

For Password reset email, when they click action link, they see the "New Password" default page and reset.

So I create my own reset password page and change the action link in email template, [reset password action link][1].

But the issue is that that action link is changed all other email template.

So my question is that how can I create the action link, [verify email action link][2].

Or how can I redirect base on mode param from reactjs app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to customize the URL only for a single email template. It says them same in the console.

[image]

There's a query parameter `mode` in those URLs. You can read that and then redirect as needed or use Firebase SDK to verify the `oobCode` in the link on the same page.

Checkout [Create the email action handler page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page) section in the documentation for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I will create the email action handler page.